# Twitter Bootstrap - format text in to paragraph

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to place my text within a div class="span3" but it just displays as a long 1-line string in the browser.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="span3" style="padding-bottom:25px">
     <%= link_to image_tag(illustration.image_thumbnail_url), illustration %>
   </div>
   <div class="span3">
     <h4><%= illustration.name + " - " + illustration.source%></h4>
     <p><%= illustration.description %></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you present us with test page or code ?

Answer (score 1):

Twitter Bootstrap system utilizes [12 columns grid](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem). So, you must open a `<div class="row">` and than you must have one or many `spans` - sum must be 12, for example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4">...</div>
  <div class="span8">...</div>
</div>
```

I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve, but you haven't open the `<div class="row">` and the sum of your `spans` is not 12.

You might be able to open the `row` together with your `container`:

```
<div class="container row">
   <div class="span6" style="padding-bottom:25px">
     <%= link_to image_tag(illustration.image_thumbnail_url), illustration %>
   </div>
   <div class="span6">
     <h4><%= illustration.name + " - " + illustration.source%></h4>
     <p><%= illustration.description %></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT** - Try to do the interpolation in this way:

```
<%= "#{illustration.name} - #{illustration.source}" %>
```

You can also use `html_safe` to display the description:

```
<%= illustration.description.html_safe %>
```

Take a look in this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-string

Comment: You can actually get away with the spans not adding up to 12.  My problem was not having spaces in the string I was testing so it displayed in a long single-line string.

Comment: @user1810434 Can you post an example of what you actually get and how do you want it to be?

Comment: I don't know if I understood it right, but I have edited my answer.